# Prove $f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x \to 0 \implies \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt = o(\int_{0}^{x} g(t)dt)$ as $x \to 0$ (Tom Apostol Calculus vol $1$, ex $7.11:31$)

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Given two functions $f$ and $g$ with derivatives in some interval containing $0$, where $g$ is positive, we should prove:

$f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x \to 0 \implies \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt = o(\int_{0}^{x} g(t)dt)$ as $x \to 0$

Let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt,  G(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g(t)dt, h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.

By the hypothesis, we know $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = 0$

Because $g$ is positive near 0 (and at 0), we have that $h(x)$ is continuous, so $h(0) = 0$.

Because of the FTC, we know $G'(x) = g(x)$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$, so we have $h(0) = \frac{F'(0)}{G'(0)} = 0$.

Then, by derivative definition we have $\frac{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h}}{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{G(h) - G(0)}{h}} = \frac{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h)}{h}}{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{G(h)}{h}} = 0$

The last equality can be true only if $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{G(h)}{h} \ne 0$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h)}{h}$ exists*, so we have

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(h)}{G(h)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{F(h)}{h}}{\frac{G(h)}{h}} = \frac{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h)}{h}}{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{G(h)}{h}} = 0$

Which concludes the proof.

I know there is [a simpler proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/129503/942378), but could someone tell me if the above is also a correct proof?

*This is the main part I'm not sure about.

Comment: You are basically using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @Gary I added a proof which does not require the L'Hôpital's rule, and which should be correct (Tom Apostol didn't introduce L'Hôpital's rule before that exercise, so I suppose he had another solution in mind for that exercise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, my proof above is wrong:

> ...
> Then, by derivative definition we have $\frac{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h) - F(0)}{h}}{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{G(h) - G(0)}{h}} = \frac{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h)}{h}}{\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{G(h)}{h}} = 0$
>
> The last equality can be true only if $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{G(h)}{h} \ne 0$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(h)}{h}$ exists*, so we have
> ...

There are many examples of finite limits, where the limit of the denominator is 0.

A corrected proof is as follows.

By hypothesis: $\tag{1} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$

Because both $g, f$ are differentiable in an interval containing 0, and $g$ is also positive there, we have:

$\tag{2} \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = g(0) > 0 \land \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$

Together $1 \land 2 \implies \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0) = 0$

Let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt,  G(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g(t)dt$.

Then $G(0) = 0$ and $F(0) = 0$.

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{F(x) - F(0)}{x} = F'(0) = f(0) = 0 \land \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{G(x) - G(0)}{x} = G'(0) = g(0) > 0 \tag{3}$

Together with $3$ we have: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)}{G(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{F(x) - F(0)}{x}}{\frac{G(x) - G(0)}{x}} = \frac{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x) - F(0)}{x}}{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{G(x) - G(0)}{x}} = 0$

That means $F(x) = o(G(x))$ as $x \to 0$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: The question assumes differentiability of $f, g$ near $0$ and not at $0$. Same for positivity of $g$. The right approach is to use LHospital Rule (or repeat its proof for this scenario).

Comment: I clarified the question to be exactly the same as mentioned in the book (7.11.31), so it becomes obvious that the proof can be simpler than the L'Hopital's theorem proof, because the latter does not assume the functions are differentiable at the point where the limit is taken.

Comment: Well with the updated question the proof is simpler. Just use the definition of derivatives and then $F(h) /G(h) $ tends to $F'(0)/G'(0)=f(0)/g(0)=0$. I wonder why Apostol gave such hypotheses about differentiability of $f, g$ in some interval containing $0$.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I did in the answer?